# tensorial product of C*-algebras and adjointness

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given $M,N$, $R$-modules, it is standard verification that $-\otimes Z$ is left adjoint to $Hom(Z,-)$.

If we have more structure, particularly if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are C*-algebras, choosing any suitable norm in the purely algebraic tensor product (so that the product is still a C*-algebra), what more adjunctions arise from this construction ?